# Bootstrap carousel indicators and controls not working with twig

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap carousel using twig. The following code works and load the data and images properly, however when clicking on indicators or on the arrow controls nothing happens. Carousel works (it changes the images), but not the controls.

The most strange thing is that it works nicely when resizing the screen down to mobile size (xs or sm). But when the size reach md, the controls stop working...

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    {% for item in gallery %}
    {% if loop.first %}
    <div class="item active"> <img src="/images/{{ item.name }}" class="img-responsive" >
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>{{ item.Caption }}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="item"> <img src="/images/{{ item.name }}" class="img-responsive" >
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>{{ item.Caption }}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Prev</span> </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a JS error when you click on the controls, by any chance ?

Comment: Nope, no errors triggered.

Comment: Well your markup works (https://jsfiddle.net/ejne4k6b/), so there might be something else. Either you called `.carousel()` in your JS as well, or there is something preventing your clicks to trigger. Check around.

Comment: Found the problem, thanks, I leave it here in case it's useful to anybody. The problem was caused outside the code given, after calling it twice in the same template, first time for small devices, then for big devices. This resulted the carousel id to be duplicated, which caused the controls not working.